# Advantage / disadvantage of using foreign keys on every child table to all parents/grand parents, etc?

Tags: database, database-design

What is the harm, if any to link all the child tables as foreign keys with all tables above them in the hierarchy? I have a location component with 6 lookup tables:

- Continents
- Countries
- Regions
- Cities
- Neighborhoods
- Location type

Obviously each level of location is a child of the above, so it will foreign key to the parent, but what is the harm if I foreign key all of them together, that is have my cities table have:

**City table**

- continent_id (fk to continent)
- country_id (fk to country)
- region_id (fk to region)

vs only have 'region_id-fk to region'?

The benefit I see in my way is if I have to lookup cities in a continent I can go directly from city to continent without jumping to region then country then continent, but of course I am not sure of the disadvantages or if this impacts performance or anything else?

This is one one set of tables. i have many tables like this so I am trying to understand the concept so i can use it to design other tables also on my other components which are much more than 6 lookup tables.

Answer (score 1):

The harm is in the [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) (aka duplication) of data.

If you already have the FK links, repeating them in last table in the hierarchy means that you are repeating data and if you need to change it you will not have it in multiple places.

Additionally, with your multi-FK scheme, unless you add more check constrains, you can end up with inconsistent data on the `city` table (where a country and the continent don't match).

Comment: But what outweights what here? Is it better to do 2-3-4 joins to reach the parent table or have it denormalized via fks so there is a direct relation between everyone? i assume since all tables are related via FK, there is no duplication as such because they all relate. So it is not like i can enter "New York" in one table and "new yk" in the next. so the same data will exist - yes but it will always be accurate in all tables. This is a social network so performance is important, hence i am not sure.

Comment: @mikey - With your multi-FK  scheme, you can have a city in the US and in Africa, unless you add more check constraints.

Comment: Example: like Chicago to Illinois to usa to north America. yes, if i enter a wrong fK id in city table for country it could go: Chicago to Illinois to Africa to north America. But i assume this is where it will error out because there is a FK for Chicago to Illinois and Illinois to USA in the region table, so wont it check to see if 'Illinois to Africa' is not valid in region table and thus prevent a link between Chicago to Africa in city table?

Comment: @mikey - It will not check the FKs for the whole hierarchy. If you define an FK to the countries table it will ensure a valid country and another to the Continents table, it will simply ensure that it is a _valid_ continent. It will **not** ensure that the FK from country to continent is the same as in your table.

Comment: Hmm, what is the way if any to force mysql to check the entire hierarchy or parts of the hierarchy for FK validity? There must be some statement or work around because i doubt large scale systems like say a military database will have everything defined in 3NF, that would create a huge number of tables.

Answer (score 0):

@mikey - sorry, I don't think I've the reputation to comment on the other answer - anyway:

For the denormalised, single-table approach, wouldn't a composite primary key on the five (six?) columns suffice?

Another consideration when deciding between the single-table denormalised or multiple-table normalised approach is, what additional attributes are you storing for the higher level entities? For example, are you just storing city names, or do you also want latitude / longitude pairs, telephone dialing codes, things like that? The more attributes you want to store, the more duplication (and associated data management issues) you'll get in a denormlised model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally do transitive foreign keys in this way.  In general this results in a lot of extra headache and many additional opportunities for problems.  Keep things simple.  I don't see this as a denormalization problem itself.  It's just a question of keeping things manageable.  Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    control code text primary key,
    date_of_birth date not null,
    ..,..
    id serial not null unique
);

CREATE TABLE wage_salary ( -- owners have drawings, not salaries, so this avoids nulls
    employee_id int not null references employee(id),
    wage_amt numeric not null,
    per_interval interval not null,
    primary key (employee_id)
);

CREATE TABLE reported_wages ( -- for tax purposes
    employee_id int not null references wage_salary,
    year int not null,
    reported_wages numeric not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (employee_id, year),
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee(id) -- unnecessary and troublesome
);
```

There are a number of cases where that extra redundant foreign key can bite you.  Since it is enforced transitively leave it off.